# include test in source file java

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I Want to write my unit test in the same source file being tested (like you can do in D http://dlang.org/unittest.html).

I also want to be able to run the test in eclipse as i usually do with a dedicated test file.

In this example Junit complains if there is no public zero argument constructor:

```
public class Dummy {
    private String _name;

    public Dummy(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    public String name () {
        return _name;
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("dummy", new Dummy("dummy").name());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to put the test method in the "real" source code and be able to run the test (in other words how to fool the no arg constructor restriction)?

Thanks

Comment: Well the error message is clear, isn't it? A JUnit tests needs no-args constructor to create the instance of the test. Your class doesn't have such a constructor. Personally I find the idea of mixing the "real" source code with the tests *highly* irritating - those test methods are normal methods, if they reside in the source code anyone can call them.

Comment: Probably the question is not clear; any suggestions on how to put the test method in the "real" source code and be able to run the test (in other words how to fool the no arg constructor restriction).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider classical TDD (based on Kent Beck's book "Test Driven Development By Example"), where the idea is not to write tests for specific classes/methods, but rather for features that you want to implement.

That way, it really doesn't make sense to put tests in production classes.

Answer (score 0):

To run the JUnit Test framework, it internally requires a zero argument constructor to instantiate it. Generally it creates by default, if you don't have any constructor. But since you have one constructor with argument, the framework will not be able to instantiate the respective class to execute the test case. To avoid it create a blank no argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Having test methods in the same class is not possible with JUnit and is also a quite strange design choice. Well, it would be possible if you had a zero argument constructor, but still, a test class is not meant to be the class that is tested. However, you can create a test class in the same file to carry out your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second constructor without parameters if you really want to put your JUnit tests inside the same class. Nevertheless this is not the way you do it according to the java conventions.

Also it bloats the class with unnecessary test cases (unnecessary for the actual task the class should do). You should maybe think about it if it would not be better to put the test cases in a separate class.

Comment: Nope, it doesent work:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:37)

Comment: Ok. Maybe you could solve your problem if you write your own runner... But as I said/wrote before it might be better to rethink the way you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [Runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) instead of using JUnit's default [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html). Please let me know if you need help.